# emulators not showing up

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Hello everyone my emulators are open(ios and android) but are not displayed in android studio. Does anyone knows whats wrong[?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNScM.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on "File->Project Structure" [image: preview]
2. Click on "Project->Project SDK" [image: preview]
3. Choose the latest one [image: preview]
4. Click on "Apply", then, "OK"

Happy Coding :D

Answer (score 0):

How about "force quit" emulators and start them again?

It happens to me on my environment when it comes to iOS emulator.